# How to store component selector in a variable in .ts file and use it as a reference {{}} in html file in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a component named `abc.component.ts` and its selector looks

```
abc.component.ts
--------------------
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-abc'
    })
```

I want to store this selector as a variable in `app.component.ts` file as

```
    app.component.ts
    -------------------
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    let selec = "<app-abc></app-abc>";
    }

app.component.html
----------------------
<div>{{selec}}</div>           //how to use <app-abc></app-abc> here
```

How to achieve it?

I have tried like this also, but its not working too.

```
    abc.component.ts
        --------------------
            @Component({
              selector: '[app-abc]'
            })

 app.component.ts
    -------------------
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    let selec = "app-abc";
    }

app.component.html
----------------------
<div {{selec}}></div>           //how to use "app-abc" here
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Any other way, like I want to do its as mentioned above.Please help

Comment: You can't add Angular components, directives or bindings dynamically, except components as demonstrated in Robins link. There is no other way.

Comment: Thanks Günter, Can you please tell me the most easiest way to achieve the above task. More simple,more helpful. I will appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // ----- tag.ts -----
    export const TAG = 'your-tag-name';

    // ----- component.ts -----
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { TAG } from '../tag';
    
    @Component({
      selector: TAG,
      template: ''
    })
    export class MyComponent {}

    // ----- another-component.ts -----
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { TAG } from '../tag';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'another-component',
      template: `
      <header></header>
      <!-- To add a component using it's selector from a variable -->
      <${TAG}></${TAG}>
      <!-- To show a component's selector as a string -->
      <h4>{{ tag }}</h4>
      <footer></footer>`
    })

    export class AnotherComponent {
      public tag = TAG;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try like this :

**abc.component.html**

```
<div>App ABC Component</div>
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-abc',
    templateUrl: './abc.component.html'
})
export class ABCComponent  {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-abc></app-abc>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ABCComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [ [
        AppComponent,
        ABCComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question.